# Material-UI MenuItem disabled items color issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Pardon me, I'm still new to all this.

I've used makeStyles to change the color of my MenuItem items but I don't understand why the disabled items always appear looking lighter even though I've the same color settings. I want to know how to fix it, and where I went wrong.

```
export default makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      '&.MuiMenuItem-root': {
        color: '#000000',
      },
      '&.Mui-disabled': {
        color: '#000000',
      },
    },
  }),
);
```

The result:

[image: result]

Comment: Try adding `opacity: 1` also.

Comment: @kbo I'll try. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @kbo wow I can't believe it's that simple. Please put an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You probably shouldn’t have the disabled menus the same as enabled though. Would be hard for your users to know what’s what

Comment: @RichardHpa ah yes, it's just a placeholder because I can't figure out why the disabled always looks lighter no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The makeStyles call is correct and the color is right, but you need to add `opacity: 1` also.